# CSS Debugging: floating divs in wrong places

Tags: css, debugging, html, css-float, floating

On my page I want to move my "complete the look" to the top of the page. It's been floated to the right, but it seems like there is something in the entry-summary that blocks the "complete the look". I can't seem to figure out what the problem seems to be. Please tell me if you need further information.

http://md4s1307.keaweb.dk/shop/coats/petrod-coat/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `float: right` and set it to `position: absolute`, and `right: 0` to make it work:

```
.upsells {
    width: 14.9284%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

The reason is that floating it to the right will only float it in regard to its sibling. As you can see when you float it right, it floats next to its previous sibling `.woocommerce-tabs`. While with absolute positioning, you can position it relative to its parent element. As  you want it in the top right of the parent, you just need to set the `right` property to `0`.

Comment: How do I then position the related products after "complete the look" so these will not conflict? In most cases there will be 4 related products in a horizontal line?

Comment: Can’t you make it so the container for related products is 85.0716% wide, so that it doesn't overlap with the complete the look section?